# Devrait-on ignorer le "de" lors d'un tri par ordre alphabétique?

Tags: presentation

Je prépare un index pour un texte, et je me demandais comment trier par ordre alphabétique les expressions suivantes :

Devrait-on trier strictement lettre par lettre :

> Langage de programmation : xxx
>
> Langage naturel : xxx

Ou est-il préférable d'ignorer le "de" :

> Langage naturel : xxx
>
> Langage <strike>de</strike> programmation : xxx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Je pense qu’il est préférable de ne jamais ignorer un mot en milieu d’expression. Il me semble logique d’ignorer les petits mots communs (articles, notamment) en *tête* d’expression uniquement.

Remarquons que, si beaucoup d’entrées se rapportent à « langage », il peut être préférable de les regrouper. Par exemple :

> Langage: 
>      naturel 18, 27, 42
>      de programmation 3, 23, 73

Dans ce cas, on pourra ignorer le « de » dans le classement alphabétique.

Comment: Les index font aussi souvent des renvois (entrée principale à _language de programmation_ par exemple et renvoi de _programmation, language de_ vers l'entrée principale).